# PHP MYSQL: JOIN keyword table on current search-code

Tags: php, mysql, join

How can i add this sample code:

```
SELECT p.* 
  FROM products AS p
  JOIN product_keywords AS pk 
    ON p.id = pk.product_id
  JOIN keywords AS k 
    on k.id = pk.keyword_id
 WHERE k.keyword = 'blue'
```

**to my current PHP search code**

```
select b.id_parent
     , ".$com_sql."
     ,'photos' as tbl 
  from photos b 
 where b.published = 1 
    and 
      ( b.title like '%".$sch[$i]."%' 
     or b.keywords like '%".$sch[$i]."%'
      );
```

**to use my new keyword:search table?**

```
product_id  keyword     
1          keyword1 
1          keyword2 
2          keyword1 
2          keyword7 
999        keyword1 
999        keyword8
```

**instead of using my old table where keywords are in comma-list**

```
id_parent  title     description     keywords           published viewed
1          title_A   description_A   keyword1,keyword2  1          1
2          title_B   description_B   keyword1,keyword7  1          10
999        title_C   description_C   keyword1,keyword8  0          100
```

**@ANSWER FROM Ruta**
syntax error, unexpected 'IN' (T_STRING)
i changed, search only in product_keywords(table).
Have variables at the end, searching in old table. Join placed after this.
Where =en, deleted.

```
$sql_mass["photo"]="select b.id_parent,".$com_sql.",'photos' 
as tbl from photos b where b.published=1 ".$wtr.$color.$orientation.$item_id.$content_type.$editorial_sql.$adult_sql.$license_sql.$com2
OR b.id_parent IN 
         (SELECT p.product_id 
          FROM products AS p
          JOIN product_keywords AS pk 
            ON p.id = pk.product_id
          JOIN keywords AS k 
            on k.id = pk.keyword_id
           AND k.keyword like '%".$sch[$i]."%'
           GROUP BY p.product_id
        );
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query). Also, see about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT b.id_parent
     , ".$com_sql."
     ,'photos' as tbl 
  FROM photos b 
 WHERE b.published = 1 
    AND ( b.title like '%".$sch[$i]."%' 
     OR b.keywords like '%".$sch[$i]."%'
     OR b.id_parent IN 
 (SELECT p.product_id 
  FROM products AS p
  JOIN product_keywords AS pk 
    ON p.id = pk.product_id
  JOIN keywords AS k 
    on k.id = pk.keyword_id
 WHERE k.language = 'en' 
   AND k.keyword like '%".$sch[$i]."%'
   GROUP BY p.product_id
) );
```

Comment: thread edited. I tried your answer, maybe the variables "$com2" are the prolem, i don`t know.